# SQL query to separate numbers and strings

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column called duration with which data are alphanumeric in nature. I want to segregate one column into three columns and perform arithmetic in it.

Eg:

```
    Duration
    30 days
    15day
    0week
    10 week
    1 mo
    7 months 
    QS ys 90days etc.
```

- If value in duration is in days it should be multiplied by 1
- If value in duration is in weeks it should be multiplied by 7
- If value in duration is in months it should be multiplied by 30

I tried to achieve final result as follows

```
    Duration      Number     Unit       Final_Duration
    30 days       30         days       30
    15day         15         day        15
    0week         0          week       0
    10 week       10         week       70
    30 days       30         days       30
    1 mo          1          mo         30
    7 months      7          months     210
    QS ys 90days  90         days       90
```

Below is my code, i have achieved everything except the last data "QS ys 90days" is throwing error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    duration, 
    LEFT(duration, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', duration)) AS Number,
    LTRIM(RIGHT(duration, LEN(duration) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', duration ))) As Unit,
    CASE
       WHEN lower(duration) LIKE '%d%' 
         THEN LEFT(duration, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', duration)) * 1
       WHEN lower(duration) LIKE '%day%' 
         THEN LEFT(duration, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', duration)) * 1
       WHEN lower(duration) LIKE '%dd%' 
         THEN LEFT(duration, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', duration)) * 1
       WHEN lower(duration) LIKE '%w%' 
         THEN LEFT(duration, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', duration)) * 7
       when lower(duration) like '%week%' 
         then LEFT(duration, PATINDEX('%  [0-9][^0-9]%', duration)) * 7
       when lower(duration) like '%m%' 
         then LEFT(duration, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', duration)) * 30
       when lower(duration) like '%month%' 
         then LEFT(duration, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', duration)) * 30
       when lower(duration) like '%mth%' 
         then LEFT(duration, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', duration)) * 30
       when lower(duration) like '%mm%' 
         then LEFT(duration, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', duration)) * 30
     END AS  Final_Duration 
FROM
    [TEST].[dbo].[Detail]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yikes. If at all possible you need to split this into two columns permanently so you can put some constraints on this. To do calculations like your trying to do will require dynamic sql. Add to that the complexity of splitting your strings since they are kind of a mess (the last one in particular) and this is incredibly difficult to get right.

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange - store the data correctly in the first place. Going down the path you're taking, the likelihood of your code breaking every time it encounters an odd new value you hadn't considered seems high.